# React Navigation Tabs not Clickable with absolute position

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have 2 screen in react native and I wanna make the tabs navigator transparent, it works but the navigator not clickable after adding `position: absolute`, if I'm not using the absolute the background turning white (can't transparent)

this is my tabBarOptions

```
tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: true,
        activeTintColor: 'orange',
        inactiveTintColor: '#fff',
        style: {
            width: '100%',
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 10,
        },
        tabStyle: {
            paddingTop: 20,
        },
    },
```

when I clicked the `Create Order` tab nothing happen, but if I comment the `position: absolute` it's perfectly work.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a snack to reproduce the issue? I think that the problem is coming from some of the additional styles that you applied to the buttons or the View components. Here is a sample working example of the transparent tabbar with position absolute: https://snack.expo.io/@hristoeftimov/react-navigation:-transparent-tabbar

Comment: @HristoEftimov I'm not using expo, this is the git repository to my project: https://github.com/anandabayu/fmc

Comment: You might use a whole page background and give transparenccy to bottom tabbar on android, on iOS position absolute works fine. See Platform specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Add "zIndex=1" in tab bar style

```
style: {
            width: '100%',
            height: 60,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 1,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 10,
        },
```

Comment: this is the git repository to my project: https://github.com/anandabayu/fmc

Comment: still have the same issue here